# Calculating $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt {t} e^{\frac{1}{t}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt {t} e^{\frac{1}{t}}}=?$$

My try: I know that: $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}=\infty$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{e^{1/t}}=0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change variable $1/t = x$,
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t} e^{1/t}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^x} = 0 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u=\frac1t$$

Then the limit $L$ becomes $$\lim_{u\rightarrow+\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u}}e^u}}=\lim_{u\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{e^u}$$

But $$\lim_{u\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{u})'}{(e^u)'}=\lim_{u\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}e^u}=0$$

So by L'Hospital's rule, $L=0$.